# Downloading TXT from within Cefsharp browser

Tags: vb.net, chromium, cefsharp

I'm using VB.Net (Basic not C++) and signed in to my account on a website.
There's a URL to a direct text file (I can download as long as I'm signed in to my account on a regular browser).

But when trying this code it doesn't work:

```vb
Dim myWebClient As New Net.WebClient()
Dim gaga = "the URL To txt file"
myWebClient.DownloadFile(gaga, Desktop_Path & "\test.txt")
```

I think there is a way to download a file using credentials but I don't want to do that.
I just want to dynamically get access to a URL txt file from the website webserver and download through the cefsharp so it understands that I'm signed in and allow it. It can't be a FTP URL since obviously I don't have access to their webserver.

Comment: There shouldn't be anything special about VB here, this is more about interfacing with CEF#.  I don't see anything in CEF# to specifically request downloading a file, I think you would just go through the general URL loader (`IWebBrowser.LoadUrlAsync`).

Comment: There are a number of options for downloading of files, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/104/CefSharp.Test/OffScreen/OffScreenBrowserBasicFacts.cs#L491 and https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/104/CefSharp.Test/OffScreen/OffScreenBrowserBasicFacts.cs#L528 for two examples.

Comment: @amaitland ugh why is everything online in C language lol